# Castle Windsor Referencing a Service in a Framework Library

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have been googling for ages today and yesterday and am completely frustrated with Castle Windsor.  I am trying to use DI to inject a custom membership provider into my controller class.  The problem is that in my config file i refer to the service that i am implementing, in this case the abstract class MembershipProvider contained in System.Web, but i get the error at runtime "Could not convert from 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider,System.Web'to System.Type - Maybe type could not be found.
My controller factory is all setup and working so i know that everything works but it just doesnt work with referencing system.web it seems like, i dont know. Here is my code in my web.config.

```
<castle>
    <components>
      <component id="MyMembership"  service="System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider,System.Web"
        type="UserManagement.CustomMembership,UserManagement" lifestyle="PerWebRequest" />
    </components>
  </castle>
```

so in this case i have my component id, the service is the abstract class MembershipProvider in System.Web assembly, then the type i wish to supply is the fully qualified type above in the UserManagement assembly.  I just cant get it to work!

Answer (score 1):

You need to deploy `UserManagement.dll`

Comment: What do you mean deploy? Its referenced by the Castle Windsor project.

Comment: is it in your output directory? Is there no typo in the type name?

Comment: yeah all my dll's are in my bin directory, and the type name is referenced with the fully qualified namespace. The assembly for the type is correct as the intellisense picks it up. I just wonder if it has trouble reconciling the system.web reference because that seems to be the only thing that i have not done before ie: referencing a service in the framework rather than my own projects.

Comment: Nah that should not be the problem. What does the inner exception say? Have you tried `fuslogvw.exe`?

Comment: The inner exception is null so no help there unfortunately, fusion log viewer didnt show me anything, it just showed a few logs by application intellitrace.exe, successful binds  but nothing interesting, its almost like the app doesnt do any binding as my DI is in the controller factory and the app errors before it instantiates a controller

Comment: Is the `UserManagement` assembly strongly named?

Comment: I don't really see how that might be *not* working provided you didn't mistype the name, assembly is deployed, not strongly named and there's nothing in fuslogvw

Comment: i know, its driving me crazy, the code in the controller works that uses the UserManagement dll and the error messages from castle windsor arent the most helpful...

Comment: They are as helpful as they can be. It's not like .NET gives Windsor too much details as to why it can't load the type.

Comment: managed to solve problem,i did an abstract class -IMembershipProvider,inherited from MembershipProvider(from framework)then i inherited from IMembershipProvider for my custom membership class and now it works. so the line <component id="MyMembership"  service="System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider,System.Web"
        type="UserManagement.CustomMembership,UserManagement"... /> now becomes <component id="MyMembership" service="UserManagement.IMembershipProvider,UserManagement"
        type="UserManagement.CustomMembership,UserManagement"... />
So an empty class and an awful hack-not proud

Comment: I'd still be interested to know what the underlying issue was, and if that's something Windsor could help you detect. Ping me if you find out. Cheers

Comment: Yeah me too, its something i want to refactor out of my application and use correctly, i'll let you know when i get to the root of the problem. For now its nice to be finally making progress on my app again!